# Finding all the kernel source files used when compiling against a certain config file

Tags: linux

I am having some issues with finding all the kernel source files used when compiling against a certain config file? I do not want the full kernel source tree, just the one that went into building the kernel against a certain config setting, like make defconfig or make allnoconfig, etc...

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? There might be another way to do it. Or at least tell us what the issues are.

Comment: All I want to do, is to be able to view/read all of the source files (.h.c.S) that went into compiling the kernel. I don't want all the source files in the kernel directory, just the ones that went into building the kernel against my config file. Am I missing something obvious? This seems so trivial.

Comment: Yes ! It is trivial indeed ! (list all the .o files left after the build into the kernel source tree. The files you are interested in get the same names with a .c and eventually a .h etension. You'll miss a bunch of .h that you'll easily identify when carefully reading the c code and incidentally know by heart since they are likely to be repeated often) The problem is that the result will represent MANY lines of code. So many that I can tell that you'll not have finished the reading before the fille you started with becomes obsolete.